# django templates: concatenate a string with an id inside a name input

Tags: html, django, concatenation, jinja2, django-widget-tweaks

I'm working with Django `forms` and `widget_tweaks`, and I need to create an input that has html like this

```
<input type="text" name="designation{{ vente.id}}" value="{{ vente.designation }}" />
```

I've tried :

```
{% render_field modifier.designation class="form-control" value=vente.designation placeholder="désignation" name="designation"+vente.id %}
```

I can't get the concatenated string of `name`, there is something with the concatenation.

PS:  `{{ vente.id}}` is an id from my database

Thank You for your help

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Comment: Did this work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to assign the "name" to a variable first, maybe using the [`with` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with input_name="designation"|add:vente.id %}
    {% render_field modifier.designation class="form-control"
        name=input_name value=vente.designation placeholder="désignation" %}
{% endwith %}
```

---

Otherwise you could create a `input_name` variable in your view and pass that to your template.

Comment: Did this help you? Could you get it working? If so, I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but unfortunately it didn't work yet.